# React-Semantic-UI, Accordion, activeIndex with and without "exclusive={false}". Works and doesn't

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

#### Expected Result

I need to have a "closeAll" button. But using `exclusive={false}`, because I need many line opened. It doesn't work.

#### Actual Result

Just `exclusive={true}` works.

#### Version

0.77.2

#### Testcase

https://codesandbox.io/s/k2wlkoz5wr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it's being overwritten by your `activeIndex` prop.

**Update**:
You can try this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpknyzjomz) of your example.

The idea is that if you're using `exclusive={false}` you need to pass `activeIndex` as an array. Then all you have to do is change the way you update the indexes on the event handlers.

Comment: It does work, i just didn't update your state to be an array of indexes.

Comment: how? What do you mean?

Comment: @JohnSam So you can have multiple items expanded, you just need to hold your state differently. Instead of having an activeIndex, you would have an array of activeIndexes... `[0,1,2]` instead of `0`

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work, because with activeIndex of type array it doesn't work the exclusive=false!

Comment: @JohnSam I've updated my answer. It should work now.